# Using Angular2 mechanism in order to provide a dependency for a function

Tags: angular

I would like for **angular 2** to provide a dependency (i.e. `UserAccountService`) for the following function:

```
function validatePassword(userAccountService:UserAccountService) {

  return (control:AbstractControl)=> {
    return userAccountService.checkCurrentPassword(control.value)
      .map(res=> {
          if (res.json() === true) {
            return null;
          }
          else {
            return {invalid: true};
          }
        }
      );
  }
}
```

Is this possible using the object hash notation as follows:

```
{
    provide: ??,//What should I use for the 'provide' key here?
    useFactory: (userAccountService:UserAccountService) => new validatePassword(userAccountService), deps: [UserAccountService]
}
```

If so what should I use for the `provide` key?

**edit 1**: Apparently it seems to be possible to inject dependencies within a function using the `@Directive`'s `providers` as follows:

```
@Directive({
  ...
  providers: [
    {
      provide: NG_VALIDATORS,
      useFactory: (emailBlackList) => {
        return validateEmailFactory(emailBlackList);
      },
      deps: [EmailBlackList]
      multi: true
    }
  ]
})
```

See here for source: http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/03/14/custom-validators-in-angular-2.html#custom-validators-with-dependencies

I would like to adapt this to be used within the `bootstrap()` function call instead of a `@Directive`. Do you see my point?

What is more the syntax has changed: `provide()` is now deprecated in favor of the above hash notation.

**edit 2**: I have modified my code to take into account the reply:

Here is my main.ts:

```
bootstrap(AppComponent, [
  ...
  {
    provide: 'PasswordValidator',
    useFactory: (userAccountService:UserAccountService) => validatePassword(userAccountService),
    deps: [UserAccountService]
  }
]);
```

Here is my validator function:

```
export function validatePassword(userAccountService:UserAccountService) {

  return (control:AbstractControl)=> {
    return userAccountService.checkCurrentPassword(control.value)
      .map(res=> {
          if (res.json() === true) {
            return null;
          }
          else {
            return {invalid: true};
          }
        }
      );
  }
}
```

Here is the calling component:

```
constructor(private router:Router,
              private formBuilder:FormBuilder,
              private stylingService:StylingService,
              private sessionService:SessionService,
              @Inject('PasswordValidator') private PasswordValidator) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.signinForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      credentials: this.formBuilder.group({
        username: [this.credentials.username, Validators.required],
        password: [this.credentials.password, [Validators.required, this.PasswordValidator.validatePassword]]
      })
    });
  }
```

Here is the error I get:

```
browser_adapter.ts:82 TypeError: Cannot read property 'validate' of undefined
    at normalizeValidator (http://localhost:8080/vendor/@angular/forms/src/directives/normalize_validator.js:10:18)
    at Array.map (native)
    at Object.composeValidators (http://localhost:8080/vendor/@angular/forms/src/directives/shared.js:58:86)
    at coerceToValidator (http://localhost:8080/vendor/@angular/forms/src/model.js:60:48)
    at new FormControl (http://localhost:8080/vendor/@angular/forms/src/model.js:300:27)
    at FormBuilder.control (http://localhost:8080/vendor/@angular/forms/src/form_builder.js:36:16)
    at FormBuilder._createControl (http://localhost:8080/vendor/@angular/forms/src/form_builder.js:68:25)
    at eval (http://localhost:8080/vendor/@angular/forms/src/form_builder.js:54:43)
    at Function.StringMapWrapper.forEach (http://localhost:8080/vendor/@angular/forms/src/facade/collection.js:142:17)
    at FormBuilder._reduceControls (http://localhost:8080/vendor/@angular/forms/src/form_builder.js:53:39)
```

**edit 3**:

I have changed my app to use a service as follows:

```
password: [this.credentials.password, [Validators.required, (control) => this.passwordValidationService.passwordValidator(control)]]
```

With the following in the html template:

```
<div *ngIf="signinForm.controls.credentials?.controls?.password?.errors?.required" class="control-label">{{'SIGNIN_FORM.PASSWORD_REQUIRED' | translate}}</div>
<div *ngIf="signinForm.controls.credentials?.controls?.password?.errors?.passwordValidator" class="control-label">{{'SIGNIN_FORM.WRONG_PASSWORD' | translate }}</div>
```

Unfortunately the http call to the backend is **not** issued.

**edit 4**:

> Unfortunately the http call to the backend is **not** issued.

It turned out that the reason why the http call (**asynchronous**) was not issued was because I had added my **asynchronous** validator to the **synchronous** validators array.

Adding it as the third argument to the `control()` method see `FormBuilder` documentation here: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/forms/index/FormBuilder-class.html
sorted the problem. Bottom line: pass async validators as async validator argument.

***Note***: I have not added this 4th edit as a solution because it does only relate to the original question indirectly. I am marking Günter's solution as accepted.

Comment: Sorry, misinterpreted you question.

Comment: I don't get what you want. You can only inject to constructors. How does your constructor look like?

Comment: No problem Günter. I have edited my post.

Comment: There is no difference, just copy it to `bootstrap(App, [...])`

Comment: Umm. And what shall I use for the provide **key**?

Comment: `NG_VALIDATORS` is not applicable here. Is it?

Comment: I updated my answer.

Comment: I'd suggest you create a normal service instead of a validator function, this would solve most of your problems in a simple way.

Comment: Regarding using a service instead of a function, notice the validators take a function and not a function call. `password: [this.credentials.password, [Validators.required, this.PasswordValidator.validatePassword]]` Do you see any way of using a service here?

Comment: When the service has a method `validate(control:Control)` pass it like `password: [this.credentials.password, [Validators.required, (control) => myValidatorService.validate(control)]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
bootstrap(AppComponent, [
{
  provide: 'myValidator',
  useFactory: (emailBlackList) => {
    return validateEmailFactory(emailBlackList);
  },
  deps: [EmailBlackList]    }
])
```

then inject it like

```
constructor(@Inject('myValidator') private validator) {}
```

**Update**

```
bootstrap(AppComponent, [
  ...
  {
    provide: 'PasswordValidator',
    useFactory: (control:Control) => (userAccountService:UserAccountService) => validatePassword(userAccountService),
    deps: [UserAccountService]
  }
]);
```

Comment: Yes I use the first one i.e. my provide hash is within the `bootstrap()` method call. Do you have any idea what I need to use for the `provide` key?

Comment: Can `@Inject('myValidator') private validator` not have a type? I mean what is the type of `validator`?

Comment: The type is function. I don't know what the type for function is. But you can't use it for injection anyway. For a function you need to use a string or OpaqueToken as key.

Comment: I have edited my post. I get a strange error from angular 2

Comment: You need to use `Validator.compose(validator1, validator2)` if you pass more than one validator or is your validator an async validator?

Comment: Ummm. I have an array of `Validators` elsewhere that contains `minLength`, `maxLength` and `required` validators and error messages are displayed according to which error happens. I am not sure I am required to use compose. It is rather something to do with the key I suspect.

Comment: Do you know where I can find the documentation that relates to validator keys?

Comment: I don't know what validator keys is. Do you use the new or old forms module?

Comment: new: model driven forms

Comment: I see. I the new forms module you can pass an array of validators.

Comment: Try `<div>{{signinForm.controls.credentials?.controls?.password?.errors | json}}</div>` to see if an error was added for your password validator.

Comment: Sorry I was wrong in saying that the call is issued to the backend... I can confirm the custom validator does not issue any call to the backend unlike what I had said before.

Comment: I don't know what to do with this comment. You mean the validator is not called? Add a `console.log('myValidator')` to see if it is actually called.

Comment: `(control) => this.passwordValidationService.passwordValidator(control)` is not called...

Comment: Hard to tell. I might be able to help if you create a Plunker that allows to reproduce.

Comment: OK Günter: I will either post here when I find the solution or create a plunker.

Comment: I have edited my post and explained the difference between sync and async validator arguments together with a link pointing to the documentation.